# CSS last child of anything without nesting?

Tags: css, sass

I need to select the last child of anything when I add *class="very-last-child"* without nesting.

**For example,** here I need to select the very last div. Nothing more nothing less.

```
<body>
 <div class="very-last-child">
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
  <div class="select-me">
   <p>The first paragraph.</p>
   <p>The second paragraph.</p>
   <p>The third paragraph.</p>
   <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

I did try something on these lines but did not work.

```
div > :last-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

p, div{
border: 2px solid black;
}
```

> **USE CASE**: I need to add padding to the last element of my page wrapper, regardless of whatever it may be. And I am using **SCSS**.

Comment: Have you tried body > :last-child?

Comment: I did work. Go ahead and replay with a solution of sass as well

Comment: I've added a answer. Please, mark as correct to help anyone with similar problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select only the last child of a container, one would use:

```
<selector> > :last-child {
    ...
}
```

In your case,

```
body > :last-child {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit unclear what you trying to achieve because of your class names, but here's what I think you want.

```
.very-last-child > :last-child {
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

This gives 50px padding at the bottom of class `select-me`